# Dripping shower, part identification

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

My shower drips even when it is shut off. I identified that the dripping water is the hot water. I started taking apart the handle, hoping to find a washer that I need to replace, but it appears that there is no washer to be replaced. Can someone point me in the right direction on what I need to do next? I also included the picture of the access panel (behind) in case it helps.

Additionally, the part that I point with a red pen seems to be attached by something hard to the wall. Not sure what it is, or why.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There most likely is a washer on the end of the long stem.

You need to get a very deep socket or a crowfoot wrench to remove the nut holding the stem in.  Then turn the stem counter clockwise and it will come out.
This will reveal the washer on the end.

The unit is so old it may have a deteriorated seat. If you can shine some light in there and look at the condition of the seat.

Since you have great access from behind, you may want to consider changing out the entire mixing valve.

Comment: The unit (including the access panel) is only about 5 years old, but it was installed by a very old-fashioned plumber.

Comment: where are you on the planet?  This type of mixing valve has been out of use for decades in the US.

Comment: I am in the US. I removed some of the plumber's putty and added a picture to the question. I do not see where to turn with the wrench.

Comment: Remove all of the putty.  Then get a wrench on the flats of the brass nut and turn counter clockwise.

Comment: Did that plumber have that thing sitting in his shop since 1985?

Comment: @RMDman  It looks like a used faucet. The couplings on the inlets and outlet points to it being cut out of somewhere and being re installed. Plus the tile is a mismatch.

Comment: Removed. However, there is something hard holding that part. Added a picture (with red pen).

Comment: I can't tell what that is...but if it's in the way get it out of there.

Comment: @CluelessAboutDIY  It looks like part of the lath holding the mortat/thinset in place. Cut or chip it out.